# Is it possible to use an Image Style in a text field?

Tags: nodes, media, wysiwyg

Image Styles is a great feature in Drupal. Is it possible to apply a preset Image Style to an image that is brought into a long text type field that uses WYSIWYG in Drupal 7? That is, for use in the basic node, not in a View.

Currently, we're using the IMCE WYSIWIG bridge to insert images in the textfield, and there seems to me no way to indicate what preset Image Style to use.

Comment: The important part is **how** do you put image in text. For example, if you use [Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert), it's readily available, clearly visible and you shouldn't need to ask.

Comment: IMHO, insert seems a little risky since it hasn't been updated since 2013.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use insert, I'm asking what are you using. For the module, just see it's code. It's simple thing. Updating when it's not broken and not in need of new features would be stupid. And it's purpose is to have one and only feature, isn't it?

Comment: At this point, we are using a plain Image field type. The nice thing about this type is that it allows you to set an upload directory and then with with IMCE WYSIWIG bridge, there is an extra icon in the Insert/Edit Image window (if you are in Full HTML) that allows you to choose an image from all the image directories. Pretty slick when an image may be used multiple times, in various places. The only lack is that Image Styles are not available in that window.  Not sure if I should make a comment about your manners. Tsk, tsk.

Comment: @Mołot, the field to pick a preset Image Style is *only* readily available in the Drupal 6 version of **Insert**.  It has not been ported to the Drupal 7 version yet.  Please see [this issue in the project's issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2477073) for details.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "possible" `:-)`.

The [**Scald**](https://drupal.org/project/scald) module (integrates with the WYSIWYG CKeditor) uses something called "contexts" that in turn makes use of the preset image styles.  So it is certainly possible to do this if you use **Scald** to insert images into WYSIWYG.

**Scald** has a drag'n'drop UI that allows you to place an image (or "atom" in Scald-speak) into WYSIWYG. When you do that, you can set its legend (i.e. caption), context and alignment (see sample dialog below):

[image]

In this case, the "Context" is set to "Full page". which I have associated with the preset Image Style known as "Large 480x480".

Below, you can see the markup that is *generated* by **Scald** as a result of this, and you can see that it links to the image using the path:

```
public:://styles/large/public/thumbnails/image/fredespenbenth.jpg
```

the `styles/large` path is indeed the image cache for the preset "Large 480x480" image style.

```
<div class="dnd-atom-wrapper type-image context-sdl_editor_representation atom-align-right" contenteditable="false">
<div class="dnd-drop-wrapper"><!-- scald=2:sdl_editor_representation {"link":""} -->
<div class="image"><img alt="Fred Espen Benth" src="http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/thumbnails/image/fredespenbenth.jpg?itok=TwJhh_s6" style="height:320px; width:480px" title="Fred Espen Benth" /></div>
<!-- END scald=2 --></div>

<div class="dnd-legend-wrapper" contenteditable="true">
<div class="meta"><!--copyright=2-->This is the caption that will appear under the image.<!--END copyright=2-->.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, as you can see, **Scald** is doing this, so it must be possible.

And you can (to some extent) do the same thing *without* **Scald** by inserting similar markup "by hand" or with the help your own custom module.  But **Scald** has in place additional magic to regenerate that style of the image in the image cache if it does not exist.  If you do this just by inserting the markup, you can't be sure that the image exists in that style, so you have to use other means to make sure the image cache is populated with the styles you actually use.  (For example sniffing for URLS pointing into the cache in `hook_preprocess_node()`, and regenerate those that are missing.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will be working on the site this afternoon and will give it a try! I will post how it works for my client.

Comment: This module has been updated the most recently of the three suggested modules - Dec. 2014. That is after the big security issues of last summer, so I will start here!

Comment: In this specific case, we won't be able to use Scald. There have been quite a lot of out of memory errors with this site, which we have corrected with php.ini and setting the memory in settings.php, but this module has put it over the maximum allowed on the web host.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins anything that uses filters will eat your RAM, you know that, right? Images are simply big things. You need image size in pixels * 4 bytes just to open one for editing. Twice to thrice that if you want to actually **do** something. And a bit more to keep output if you want to use any format with compression, like jpg. You may need more than 64MB just to handle a photo from smartphone. Are you sure you really can do it? Because it may be a problem not related to this particular module.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins example (forgot to demonstrate in prev comment): my cellphone takes 20Mpx photos. 4 bytes per pixel uses 80MB RAM just to open it. 160 to 240 to apply effects, and about 4 to save. To be safe you would need to be able to allocate more than 244MB + what script needs. Say, 256MB / request. No matter how lightweight the module is, because we are only counting image library and bare Drupal needs. Of course once generated, styled image is reused, but you need that much memory on the first display, no way around it (except if you can limit image size on upload).

Comment: Thank you for your in depth examples! I believe that Ubercart is what pushed this site over the top. Everything takes resources from everything else. If you choose this, it means that you can't have that. The web host is also not optimized for Drupal, but they are local ... Unfortunately, 256 M is as high as the host will allow.

Comment: **Scald** is a media library manager (just like **IMCE**) that integrates well with WYSIWYG.  AFIK, it doesn't use more memory than **IMCE** or **Media** (the two main alternatives)  The module's footprint is only about [150Kbyte](https://www.drupal.org/node/2101855). Memory problems happens if your *images* are huge, as filtering a big image for downsizing to a specific image styles eats memory. I am using it on a number of newspaper/magazine sites with a 128M PHP `memory_limit` with no issues (but I don't use **Ubercart**).

Comment: That was exactly the information I needed to send to my client, who has uploaded at least one image that is 5.5 M because Drupal will resize it!
Relevant to your answer, but not to the original question is the fact that Scald was very difficult to remove. I had to restore the database to pre-install and delete the files, as there was no "delete" option in the module list.

Comment: There is no "delete" option in the module list for *any* Drupal module. You remove **Scald** as you remove any Drupal module - by first disabling and then uninstalling it.  Maybe you need to employ somebody who actually knows Drupal?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this can be done with the module found on:
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_filter

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will be working on the site this afternoon and will give it a try! I will post how it works for my client.

Comment: Hmmm, this one has been updated more recently than the first suggestion. The last update was June 2014.

Comment: This module requires that the images be added as image nodes, possibly using ImageFields. Unfortunately, it would traumatize my client too much to replace all their hard work adding images to the site to convert them.